# выборка данных из localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, localhost

```
    <td>   <select class = "list">
                               <option>Передние колодки(1 пара)замена</option>
                               <option>Суппорт передний (1)замена</option>
                               <option>Главный тормозной циллиндр замена</option>
                               <option>Вакуумный усилительтормозной системы</option>
                               <option>Регулятор тормозного усилия -замена</option>
                           </select></td>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" /></td>
///
<td>   <select class = "list">
                               <option>Тормозной шланг перед/зад -замена</option>
                               <option>Рабочий цилиндр задний</option>
                               <option>тормозная жидкость замена</option>
                               <option>Шаровая опора верхняя</option>
                               <option>Регулятор тормозного усилия -замена</option>
                           </select></td>
           <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" /></td>
        </tr>
```

есть два селекта и база данных в localhost phpmyadmin никак не могу додуматься как сделать так, чтобы при выборе 1 из видов работ ( в option) с права появлялась его цена. Соответственно, если выбрать другой вид работ ,то выйдет уже цена выбранного option. как видите есть два selecta по 5 option. при выборе например в 1 селекте одного из вида работ то выйдет его цена , анологично и во 2. в базе данных есть id /nameofwork/ priсe. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Твои select и option находятся в браузере клиента.
А база данных на сервере БД.

Браузер клиента не может постучаться в твою базу данных. Это может сделать только бэкэнд-приложение, написанное на php например.
Ты должен из браузера послать ajax-запрос на бэкэнд, а тот в свою очередь сделать выборку из базы данных, получить цену и вернуть во фронтенд. На фронтенде ты принимаешь значение и отображаешь его в браузере где тебе нужно.

Answer (score 0):

У каждого вида работ должен быть `id`. По нему достаем цену.

Информацию о ценах (`workPrice`) лучше подгружать сразу при генерации страницы.

```js
const workPrice = {
  '1': 500,
  '2': 700,
  '3': 1100,
  '4': 1500,
  '5': 2200,
}

$('.list').change(function(){
  const val = $(this).val();
  $('.price').val(workPrice[val]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="list">
        <option value="1">Передние колодки(1 пара)замена</option>
        <option value="2">Суппорт передний (1)замена</option>
        <option value="3">Главный тормозной циллиндр замена</option>
        <option value="4">Вакуумный усилительтормозной системы</option>
        <option value="5">Регулятор тормозного усилия - замена</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      цена: <input type="text" value="500" class="form-control price" readonly/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```